# Как определить путь к файлу внутри приложения?

Tags: android

Создал временный файл, из которого собираюсь дёргать разного рода информацию для тестов приложения. Попробовал достичь его, как когда-то в `IDEA`:

```
Map<String, Good> goods = parser.fill("./app/src/main/java/ru/xpendence/developer/gimstopwatch/foodstuffs/calories.xls");
```

Но файл не находит. Очевидно, способ получить путь к файлу в `Android` немного другой, чем в проекте `IDEA`. Прошу помощи.

Comment: А где собственно файл лежит?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `app.java.ru.xpendence.developer.gimstopwatch.foodstuffs`

Comment: Думаю, вам надо в  `assets` папку файл сложить..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Хорошая идея. Но как её проявить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте папку `assets` в проекте и кладите файл туда. Чтобы считать, например в `InputStream`:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("calories.xls");
```

Папку создать можно через *File > New > Folder > Assets Folder*

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!