# Не находит файлы и каталоги Java.io.file

Tags: java, android

По разному пишут, где то путь например `File file = new File("C://wall.png")`;
 А где то `File file = new File("C:\\wall.png");` Есть места где пишут и через одинарный слэш. Я в итоге получаю NPE. Пробовал по всякому, но чтобы продолжить дальше искать в чем проблема, надо наверняка узнать какой слэш использовать или нет разницы ?

Например в папке scr лежит `wall.png` 
объявляю `public File file;`
инициализирую `file = new File("wall.png");`
получаю битмап `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));` но тут подчеркивается `new FileInputStream(file)` после того как я напишу сюда file и ошибка: Unhandled exception .

Если положу файл wall.png в корень диска C и укажу `file = new File("C:\\wall.png");` или `file = new File("C://wall.png")`; результат не меняется.

**UPD**

```
if (new File("wall.png").exists()) {
    System.out.println("ЕСТь");
}else System.out.println("НЕТ");
```

не находит, а файл лежит в папке scr

**UPD1** 
объявил

```
File file;
File[] paths;
```

в `onCreate` пишу

```
file = new File("");
paths = file.listFiles();
System.out.println(paths);
```

В ответ должен получить все файлы и каталоги корневой папки проекта. А получаю null. По этой же не понятной для меня причине и не находятся файлы по абсолютным путям. Что же я не так делаю

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в явах, но у меня есть подозрение, что она заимствовала интерпретацию разделителей каталогов из С/С++. Поэтому, я бы предложил использовать вместо разделителя либо одинарный прямой слэш (/), либо двойной обратный (\\), а не так, как у Вас (двойной прямой и одинарный обратный).

И как вариант, попробуйте использовать стандартный диалог выбора файла и посмотрите (хоть в отладчике), как будет храниться путь в строке.

Comment: а андроид тут причем?

Comment: c Unhandled exception я разобрался, он выпадал изза отсутствия блока  try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                }catch (IOException e){
                }

Comment: Тооооочно... я на компе через эмулятор проверяю, а файл закинул в диск С в корень..надо ведь в проект положить . Но положив в scr и написав file = new File("wall.png"); всё равно получаю исключение

Comment: смотрю что для андроид слэш / , для винды \\

Comment: `/` должен подойти для всего. Даже виндовс на самом деле использует  `/`. Просто в командной строке почему-то принимает только \. Один `/` должен быть один и в строке `new File("c:/wall.png")`. \ должен экранироваться, потому что сам является экраном. `new File("c:\\wall.png")`.  И если файл лежит в папке src, то правильно что не находит c:\wall.png, ибо тут даже намёка нет на src

Comment: Я ошибся, написав вообще букву С так как речь идет об андроид, я просто работал на эмуляторе и затупил,  файл так то должен быть в проекте. Если писать new File("wall.png") подразумевается корень проекта. Я уже перепробовал во все папки в проекте закинуть и ни где файл не находится. Т. е.  я даже слэш не использую, но всё равно файл не находится

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671283/14141). Тут есть нужный вам ответ.

Comment: Там нет нужного мне ответа. там предлагается использовать InputStream для работы напрямую с потоками, а File предназначен для управления информацией о файлах. И тем более подключенная библиотека на вход требует именно File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, почитайте про относительный и абсолютный путь. Абсолютный указывает реальное местоположение в файловой системе, например, `C:\Program Files`. Относительный же ищет относительно рабочей директории. То есть если вы работаете в `C:\Program Files`, и введете в пути File `wall.png`, без каких-либо уточнений, то к данному имени будет добавлен в начало путь до директории, в которой вы работаете сейчас, в нашем примере полный путь окажется: `C:\Program Files\wall.png`.

Про слеши. Если вы пользуетесь `\`, то его необходимо экранировать. Некоторые символы без экранирования носят не тот смысл, что бы в них хотите заложить. Например, строка `\n` - переход строки, а `\\n` возвратит строки `\n`, так как слеш был экранирован.

Соответственно, если вы хотите использовать такие слеши `\`, то их нужно экранировать и ваш путь получиться следующим (абсолютный): `C:\\Program Files\\wall.png`. Если вы не хотите все время думать об экранировании, то используйте обратные слеши, с ними ваш путь будет выглядеть как: `C:/Program Files/wall.png`.

Разумеется, вам необходимо поставить свой путь до файла вместо (абсолютного) `C:/Program Files`.

Comment: Ну хорошо, использую я обратный слеш /. И путь я пишу абсолютный C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProjects/app/wall.png и файл там лежит действительно . Объявил public File file. В onCreate инициализирую  file = new File("C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProjects/app/wall.png");   Но ничего не находит

Comment: Вы хотите открыть картинку, или же найти ее в файловой системе (ФС)? Если найти в ФС, то сделайте что-то типо

File f = new File ('C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProjects/app');
f.exists('wall.jpg');

Не проверял, но по идее должно работать. Я не специалист, но File не для открытия файлов, а поиска и работы с директориями и всего такого. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Я ее хочу зайти в файловой системе. А файловая система андроид не имеет такого пути,  где есть диск С и так далее.  В этом то и была ошибка.